# Rspec test for login user.CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

I am trying to create rspec test for ability class. I successfully wrote the  ability for the admin and testing this, but I don't know how write the test for the login user(login user can only update and destroy its own comments).

This is ability.rb:

```
    class Ability
      include CanCan::Ability

      def initialize(user)
        user ||= User.new
        if user.admin?
          can :manage, :all
        else
          can :read, :all
          can :create, :update, :destroy, Comment, user_id: user.id
        end
      end
    end
```

and this is ability_spec.rb:

```
    require 'rails_helper'
    require "cancan/matchers"

    describe Ability do
        it "user guest" do
            user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            ability = Ability.new(user)
            comment = Comment.new(user: user)
            expect(ability).to be_able_to(:read, comment)
        end

        it "user admin" do
            user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, role: 'admin')
            ability = Ability.new(user)
            comment = Comment.new(user: user)
            expect(ability).to be_able_to(:destroy, comment)
        end
```

Comment: I know this does answer your question, but I thought a proper PSA would be in order.  Avoid using Cancan as the gem is no longer being actively maintained. It hasn't been updated in over a year, nor has it been fully tested for Rails 4+.  I would recommend using CanCanCan (a fork of the orginal project) or Pundit.

Comment: thank you man, but I need just CanCan

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your spec_helper RSpec.configure.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  ...
end
```

This is to use devise helper in your specs. like sign_in(user).
So, for testing logged in user you can first sign the user
like this

```
it "user admin" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, role: 'admin')
    sign_in(user)
    # your code to test update and destroy ability
end
```