# Rspec + Cancan error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, cancan

**admin_spec.rb**

```
it "checks access for user" do
  visit rails_admin_path
  login(:user) #helper method
  expect(page).to raise_error(CanCan::AccessDenied)
end
```

**console output**

```
Failure/Error: login(:user)
CanCan::AccessDenied:
  You are not authorized to access this page.
```

But test still is red. Why and how fix it?

Comment: Could you show us what your login helper method looks like and what you are stubbing user with?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Frylock13/367ccf9dac2962e587c6
`:user(user@gmail.com)` doesn't have access to admin page, `:admin(admin@gmail.com)` does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this article?

[Testing abilities in CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities)

Instead of actually visiting the URL, maybe you can use the can? method to determine if the :user is allowed to visit the rails admin path.

I'm assuming you're using Devise? If so, I found this other SO article that may be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27605093/rspec-test-for-login-user-cancan). They suggest including a block to allow devise test helpers.

Alternatively, switch to CanCanCan (that's what we currently use) and it works MUCH easier (since CanCan is no longer supported):

```
  context 'sign_in' do
    scenario 'with valid information should redirect to the administration dashboard', :js => true do
      sign_in_with sign_in_url, registered_user.email, 'validpassword', 'admin_user'

      expect(page).to have_content('Site Administration')
    end

    scenario 'with invalid information', :js => true do
      sign_in_with sign_in_url, registered_user.email, 'invalidvalidpassword', 'admin_user'
      expect(page).to have_content('Invalid email or password')
    end
  end
```